# How do I reset Auto-Increment to start from 1 in built-in SQL Database of C# after deleting contents from table?

Tags: c#, .net

*How do I reset Auto-Increment to start from 1 in built-in SQL Database of C# after deleting contents from table ?*

[image]

The problem I am facing is that, when I delete all the contents from the table with the "DELETE" query and again try to insert new data the "Id" will start from 100 whereas I am expecting it to be start from 1. Can anyone help me to solve this issue where the Primary Key i.e., "Id" starts from its seed which is "1" ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you want to reset the sequence? Even if it's unlikely, someone could have stored your id previously which now refers to a different entry - making it not unique anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can  set a new current identity value for the identity column with the query below

DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sure.thanks. I'm just amatuer in answering questions.